# fancybox on div double click

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

My requirement is that on doubleclicking a div, another div should open as fancybox.. How can this be done in Jquery with rails 3.1

I have the following function inside document.ready()

```
$("#a1").dblclick(function () {
  $.get("/projects/edit/"+this.id,{
  u:$('#user').val()
  },
  function(data)
  {
  $("#edit_proj").fancybox();
  $("#edit_proj").html(data);

  });
```

But the edit_proj div is not opening in fancybox.. I dont know how to open it in fancybox..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the structure of your `divs` neither if the `<div id="edit_proj"></div>` exist or not in your document structure (you could evaluate that and append dynamically the `div` to a parent container though) ... so guessing that you have this (rendered html) structure :

```
<div id="a1">double click me</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

... where `#container` is (will be) the parent `div` of `#edit_proj`, then you could try this script

```
$("#a1").dblclick(function() {
    $.get("/projects/edit/" + this.id, {
        u: $('#user').val(),
    }, function(data) {
        if ($("#edit_proj").length == 0) {
            console.log("it doesn't exist"); // so append it
            $("<div id='edit_proj' />").appendTo("#container").html(data);
            $.fancybox("#edit_proj"); // fancybox
        } else {
            console.log("it does exist"); // so add data
            $("#edit_proj").html(data);
            $.fancybox("#edit_proj"); // fancybox
        }
    }); // get
}); // dblclick
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jPm2d/)**

**IMPORTANT**: Bear in mind that since your are using `inline` content, fancybox will return `<div id='edit_proj'></div>` to its place in the document structure with the property `display:none;`

**NOTE** : This demo uses fancybox v2.1.3+.

Answer (score 0):

make sure `#edit_proj` exist on your page also change this

```
 $("#edit_proj").fancybox();
  $("#edit_proj").html(data);
```

to this

```
  $("#edit_proj").html(data);
 $("#edit_proj").fancybox();
```